# Is the routing is possible from public server to private server of same VPC

Tags: routes, amazon-vpc

so, my problem statement is: I'm running multiple servers, some of them are in private subnet & some of them are in the public subnet of the same VPC. All private servers are accessible from public servers only. I want to make my max request communication to the internal network. So I kept my API server into a Private subnet.

```
private server: running RDS, and some API's
public server: running frontend Application & nginx
```

So, Is there any way so that when a user comes to my application, All my API request goes from public server to the private server.
There are some webhook requests also that gets trigger when a user submits his selection.

**my aim is to keep all my server communication to be internal**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.
To access an API endpoint in an EC2 Instance in a Private subnet from the Internet you have many ways - example

1. Create internal load balancer for private instances and access it from public instances, you can do path base routing to achieve result for multiple APIs (easiest and efficient way to achieve it).
   These links will help you - 
    https://dbseer.com/access-ec2-instance-private-subnet-internet/
    https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-amazon-api-gateway-private-endpoints/
2. Do internally within your application and need to apply path based routing within your application on public instances, need to modify your DNS settings on public EC2(manual approach to get the same result and not recommended)

To troubleshoot LB and setting up health check follow these -

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-troubleshooting.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/target-group-health-checks.html
- https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-fix-failing-health-checks-alb/

Comment: this configuration of the route table is for communication inside the VPC. i.e for internal communication. that is working fine for me.... you didn't understand my problem statement.

It is, for all the requests that coming from outside to my private server, should go through public server.

Comment: Thanks @abhishek, I hope the updated answer would help

Comment: yeah. Thanks, this is working. but It is getting failed at the ALB health check. 
my load balancer is listening on port 80 and 443, all traffics of port 80 is redirected to port 443, and my target group is listening on port 80. anything wrong with the conf?

Comment: healthcheck is done on a port and/or url(depending on LB) on your target instances. If those are listening on 80 port and you can hit them from other private instances, the load balancer should also hit them successfully. Updating the answer, you can accept if it answers your question